# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a checkbox and textbox. When the checkbox is checked, textbox is visible, I want.But I have some error

```
<asp:CheckBox  type="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkAnswer2" onClick="openclose(this.checked, 'txtquestionAnswer1');" />

<asp:TextBox id="txtquestionAnswer1" Visible="false" style="resize:none;"  TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

And java script Part:

```
function openclose(check, id) {
        if (check)
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
```

But I have this error: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null*

How to fix this problem?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

The `id` you give an `asp:TextBox` is not the ID it has on the client; that's `ClientID`. So:

```
<asp:CheckBox  type="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkAnswer2" onClick="openclose(this.checked, '<%= txtquestionAnswer1.ClientId %>');" />
<!-- Change is here ---------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  -->

<asp:TextBox id="txtquestionAnswer1" Visible="false" style="resize:none;"  TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Comment: +1 Another approach would be to set the `ClientIDMode` property to `Static` this way it doesn't matter how many `INamingContainers` the textbox is child of...

Comment: @T.J. I tried your method but I have same error. Maybe I should some change my javascript?

Comment: @Bip: No, the JavaScript is fine -- other than the shocking lack of `{` and `}`! ;-) You need to find out what the actual `id` of the text box is on the page; use the dev tools of your browser. Then once you know that, you need to figure out how to get that value in your server-side code so you can output it to the checkbox. Or as Leo points out above, switch to `ClientIDMode`.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net generates new id's for the elements when translating them to plain html.

you have 2 options:

either set clientIdMode="static" to keep the same id you set,

or use preprocessor directive to instruct visual studio to get the newly generated id insead:

```
"#<%= chkAnswer2.ClientID%>"
```